# PHP zip results in flat folder structure

Tags: php

I am using a PHP zip function created by a former employee. It compresses files and folders but I'm having two problems with the resulting ZIP file:

a. It doesn't include the 'main' folder
b. It doesn't keep the parent/child folder structure

What I want is to have the child folders under the parent folders, like so:

```
Parent1
   +-- Child1a
   +-- Child1b
Parent2
Parent3
   +-- Child3a
      +-- Subchild3a1
      +-- Subchild3a2
```

But what I'm ending up with is a flat folder structure in the ZIP file:

```
Parent1
Child1a
Child1b
Parent2
Parent3
Child3a
Subchild3a1
Subchild3a2
```

How do I resolve this issue using the following code:

```
<?php

function folderToZip($folder, &$zipFile, $subfolder = null) {
    if ($zipFile == null) {
        return false;
    }

    $folder .= end(str_split($folder)) == "/" ? "" : "/";
    $subfolder .= end(str_split($subfolder)) == "/" ? "" : "/";

    $handle = opendir($folder);

    while ($f = readdir($handle)) {
        if ($f != "." && $f != ".." && $f != "archive") {
                if (is_file($folder . $f)) {
                        if ($subfolder != null)
                        $zipFile->addFile($folder . $f, $subfolder . $f);
                        else
                        $zipFile->addFile($folder . $f);
        } elseif (is_dir($folder . $f)) {
                $zipFile->addEmptyDir($f);
                folderToZip($folder . $f, $zipFile, $f);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php

$z = new ZipArchive();
$z->open("test.zip", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
folderToZip("c:/path/to/look/for/files/to/compress/", $z);

echo "<br />Done";

$z->close();

$ex_file = "./archive/back-" . date('Ymd_Hi', time()) . ".zip";

rename("test.zip", $ex_file);

?>
```

**EDIT:** Here's the script that finally worked for me:

```
<?php

function folderToZip($folder, $zipFile, $subfolder = null) {
    if ($zipFile == null) {
        return false;
    }

    $folder .= end(str_split($folder)) == "/" ? "" : "/";
    $subfolder .= end(str_split($subfolder)) == "/" || $subfolder == NULL ? "" : "/";

    $handle = opendir($folder);

    while ($f = readdir($handle)) {
      if ($f != "." && $f != ".." && $f != "archive") {
                if (is_file($folder . $f)) {
                        $zipFile->addFile($folder . $f, $subfolder . $f);
        } elseif (is_dir($folder . $f)) {
                $zipFile->addEmptyDir($subfolder . $f);
                folderToZip($folder . $f, $zipFile, $subfolder . $f);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php

$z = new ZipArchive();
$z->open("test.zip", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
folderToZip("c:/path/to/look/for/files/to/compress/", $z);

echo "<br />Done";

$z->close();

$ex_file = "./archive/back-" . date('Ymd_Hi', time()) . ".zip";

rename("test.zip", $ex_file);

?>
```

Comment: Are any directories being created inside the ZIP? (best to specify them by adding / after any directories in the output, ie. `Parent1/`)

Comment: Yes, folders are being created but they're all on the same Parent level. Inside the folders there are files -- except the files in the 'main' folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code appears to be incorrect:

```
} elseif (is_dir($folder . $f)) {
   $zipFile->addEmptyDir($f);
   folderToZip($folder . $f, $zipFile, $f);
}
```

I believe it should be:

```
} elseif (is_dir($folder . $f)) {
   $zipFile->addEmptyDir($subfolder . $f);
   folderToZip($folder . $f, $zipFile, $subfolder . $f);
}
```

Without referencing the $subfolder and passing it back into the recursive function, you are always referencing '/' or the root of the zip file.

Comment: What that did was create a ZIP file of about the right size -- but it's empty.

Comment: Issue might be that you are adding a slash if subfolder is null to begin with. Skip it on null, like: `$subfolder .= (end(str_split($subfolder)) == "/" || $subfolder == NULL) ? "" : "/";`. On mobile so cant test but that might be  throwing it off. Also, its good practice to specify localname in addfile regardless of subfolders.

Comment: As an extension of the specify local name in addfile regardless of subfolder, i would also suggest removing the: `if ($subfolder != null)` and `else $zipFile->addFile($folder . $f);` part.