# Create flat directory from zip

Tags: php, laravel, recursion

In my controller I receive ZIP file, which may contain xml and nested multi level zip files.
How to create flat directory, which will contain only xml files recursively extracted from all zip files?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/q/30605053/19168006 you can do if statement to check .xml extention.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend for the sake of simplicity, creating a temporary directory, extracting the ZIP to that directory:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('tmp');
    $zip->close();
    
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

then, maybe a recursive function to iterate all files.

```
function recursiveDirectoryIterator($path){
    $out = [];
    foreach(glob($path . "/*") as $entry){ 
         if ( is_dir($entry) ) {
             $sub = recursiveDirectoryIterator($entry);
             foreach($sub as $subEntry){ $out[] = $subEntry; }
         } else {
              $out[] = $entry;
         }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

then, to finish just use:

```
    foreach(recursiveDirectoryIterator("tmp") as $file){ 
        if ( !rename ( $file , getcwd() . basename($file) ) {
            echo 'Failed to rename: ' . $file . ' to ' . getcwd() . basename($file) . '<br>';
        }  
    }
```

if you have multiple nested ZIP archives, just amend this approach. Maybe created a key => value list of the archives, such as:

```
$archive['imagePack1'] = "tmp/archive1.zip";
$archive['imagePack2'] = "tmp/archive2.zip"

foreach($archive as $key => $path){
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open('tmp/' . $path) === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo('tmp/' . $key);
        $zip->close();

     } else {
        echo 'failed';
     }
}
```